# Filter deep nested array based on prop value and return a Record string

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, nested

I have an array of objects with unknown nesting depth (it can be 5 or even more) like this:

```
const routes: routeType[] = [
{
  path: '/user', visible: true, title: 'User'
},
{
  path: "/admin", visible: true, title: "Admin", children: [
    {index: true, visible: false},
    {path: "dashboard", visible: true, title: "Dashboard"},
    {path: "changelog", visible: true, title: "Changelog"},
    {path: "profile", visible: true, title: "Profile"},
    {path: "settings", visible: true, title: "Settings", children: [
        {index: true, visible: false},
        {path: "themes", visible: true, title: "Theme"}
        {path: "themes/new", visible: true, title: "New"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

The result I would like to obtain is a String Record composed in this way:

```
const resultMap: Record<string, string> = {
"/admin": "Admin",
"/admin/dashboard": "Dashboard",
"/admin/changelog": "Changelog",
"/admin/profile": "Profile",
"/admin/settings": "Settings",
"/admin/settings/themes": "Themes",
"/admin/settings/themes/new": "New"}
```

So:

1. Filter all records with "true" visible prop.
2. Build a string record composed of the path and title (each child path has the corresponding parent path).

There are many similar questions but none that match my needs. I struggled for two days but in the end I couldn't find a solution. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple recursive function is your friend here. Just add the correct type annotations and you're good to go.

```
function buildStringRecord(
  routes: RouteType[],
  parentPath: string = '',
  resultMap: Record<string, string> = {}
): Record<string, string> {
  for (const route of routes) {
    if (route.visible) {
      const fullPath = parentPath + route.path;
      if(route.title) {
        resultMap[fullPath] = route.title;
      }

      if (route.children) {
         buildStringRecord(route.children, fullPath + '/', resultMap);
      } 
    }
  }

  return resultMap;
}

const resultMap = buildStringRecord(routes);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukAqBPABxQG8AoZZAuMACwH4AuZAZzClAHMBuc5AN2DNgAIwA2EJsPTpxcEDwqgAJhAAejZFJkQ5C5GGBhxG1uxDdeCGsFFKoEEBozYI+IgG0AujwC+pUgjoIKzIUFiQzEzOuIQQXsgAvMjuvGQUFFS0TADkAPSYzNDZADS8FAJCYhL6UJgQpen6huI5AKqFUCW8Pg3IaemZNDm5cEoAtqBdjRUiLTV1vRQGRtXZAILjk4vIVjZ2DkwpjRTEyMpqTGwL-IKz1fCihcg9ZemngzlKcMw0UnBQShKN0qcyu9SaKxyABFvr90P9Ac9tidKNQhshslY5BwIKJ0BwgTMqpdauDlnNsgBhGjY3H47JI14oj4YghhGA2CCE27E+Zk5qrAAK7M5DJexz6TIGaJyhTABnMzCmEuBdxJCylSwFOQAyhB5Zwlcj0rtbPYQIdNW8ziAVKp1eCiXMHk9xSrmTKMbQIGMIEbVbywcUIRScDQfVzGe6PVkveHfcxciAIAB3bkg6pBkOrAByqbFxoonmNbqLvRe3n8MEwIAQBiCmkwex1bE4qAggQBAApeGEXJE0OFXLEvL0qOawILPaZOIkMcr7MxMKIwABZOAEKId9AAgA8M-MwYPHAAfHPiH4AJSSigwHfILuBYJgUJD5DoGCv-vX-qKT9dvtIAAOidCAfylJ8QmrURRCnWg53HBxJzRZAAGov2AwY9EaYAYAAocgPJMCbxVRdlzXDd3Gg2C0U8OdAIgQiBWw9I-ClXCHwYoDTX2EBwPdYQm1sFszA4dtOyUfCXG46wzQcYNqLgmg0IxXIgTIld1wIS8WIoHxkFePw9N4Xt9UwKAQFCP1yK03x-Egl8NIogg50E5tW3McSd0khjmB0gIgmYbQgLxDgAOszSN38oA)

Working Example:

```js
const routes = [ { path: '/user', visible: true, title: 'User', }, { path: '/admin', visible: true, title: 'Admin', children: [ { index: true, visible: false }, { path: 'dashboard', visible: true, title: 'Dashboard' }, { path: 'changelog', visible: true, title: 'Changelog' }, { path: 'profile', visible: true, title: 'Profile' }, { path: 'settings', visible: true, title: 'Settings', children: [ { index: true, visible: false }, { path: 'themes', visible: true, title: 'Theme' }, { path: 'themes/new', visible: true, title: 'New' } ] } ] }];

function buildStringRecord(
  routes,
  parentPath = "",
  resultMap = {}
) {
  for (const route of routes) {
    if (route.visible) {
      const fullPath = parentPath + route.path;
      if(route.title) {
        resultMap[fullPath] = route.title;
      }

      if (route.children) {
        buildStringRecord(route.children, fullPath + '/', resultMap);
      } 
    }
  }

  return resultMap;
}

const resultMap = buildStringRecord(routes);
console.log(resultMap);
```